# Question with not much attention

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently asked a question ([this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42351/variable-scoping-in-module)) that got only one answer; that answer was not particularly responsive. What's the accepted protocol if any for getting attention to that question again? Is it kosher to edit it to move it to the top of the list? If not, what? It's not that obscure, and I'm sure there are good answers out there....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for your options:

- An edit will bump it up, yes, but making a trivial edit solely to push it to the top is kinda frowned upon. In general, if it hasn't gotten much attention, you can try to add additional details/clarifications or in the case of problem solving questions, an update on the current state of your code. Since you've already done an update, there probably isn't much for you to add (maybe you have).
- You can place a [bounty](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on a question (any question, not just yours) after 2 days. This again bumps it up to the top, and is [featured](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) for 1 week or until the bounty is awarded, whichever is sooner. This comes at a rep cost to you.
- You can try asking for suggestions in chat as to how you can improve your question. You might get some useful suggestions or perhaps have a useful discussion, which paves the way for a solution.

---

As for my personal opinion on this particular question, I think it did not get much attention because Szabolcs's comment under the question and george's comment under Alexey's answer tell the full picture. In particular, `RuleDelayed` localizes the symbols preventing immediate evaluation, and `Module` will replace all instances of `a` **except** inside another scoping construct (such as `Rule` and `RuleDelayed`). Since all of this is fully described in the "More details" section of the docs for `Module` and `RuleDelayed`, people might have passed it off as RTFM.

I agree that this is not a typical RTFM question and no matter how detailed the docs are, scoping rules can be a bit difficult to grok (or remember). But Alexey's answer clearly expands on Szabolcs's comment and it seems unfair to characterize it as not answering your question.

> [...] that answer was not particularly responsive.

To be fair to Alexey and the commenters, *you* never responded to any of them! Try to engage with the people that are trying to help you. If something's not clear, ask them. I usually leave a comment and move on with other things... very rarely do I come back to see if there's an update. However if the user engages with me in the comments, I'll try to pay more attention to the post.

I know you had an update to your question, but we are not automatically notified of that. I doubt if Szabolcs or Alexey even noticed your update. If your update is a direct response to a particular comment/answer, it is a good idea to also notify them individually.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the feedback. I obviously didn't think that the answer(s) I got resolved the questions I had. I will make sure next time to explicitly add comments notifying answerers of updates.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the above question, I have written a second answer to the referenced question. I hope it makes things clearer for you.

Comment: Thanks; see my question in response in the OP.